# Clear OneSignal tags when User uninstalls App

Tags: android, tags, uninstallation, onesignal

currently I have `tags` for a user in OneSignal.

I noticed, that these tags *remain* when user `uninstalls` the app.

**How can I clear/delete the Users Tags in OneSignal when User uninstalls app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is simply to iterate through every key and set the value to an empty string.

Comment: I solved it through just getting the tags at beginning of App start and iterating through them removing one by one. But thanks for your answer!